# HTML Date Picker how to allow Date like 00.00.1990 (dd.MM.YYYY)

Tags: javascript, html, date

I have a form, where people can enter their date of birth. There are some people on this planet, which do not have a documentated date of birth so their date of birt is 00.00.1990 (for example, many people know the year but not the exact day or month). With a basic html input type date it is not possible to type in this kind of date. Is there any possibility to allow this format?

```
<label>Date of birth</label>   
<input placeholder="dd.MM.YYYY" type="date" /> //User should be possible to type in 00.00.1990
```

In this case the year 1990 is just an example, the most important thing is, that the day and the month can be 00.
Now when I type in 00.00.1990, the date picker automatically corrects it to 01.01.1990. Is there a possibility do deactivate this?

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#date-state-(type=date)) states that the value of an input type date must be either an empty string or a [valid date](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-date-string). The input's value is represented in YYYY-MM-DD format (though the display format is typically based on the language of the host system or browser).

Encoding an approximate date as 00.00.YYYY is not a good idea as it can't be represented as a Date object and requires special parsing.

Consider having two date of birth types: precise and approximate. For a precise date, store year, month and day (i.e. a valid date). For approximate types, store the known or estimated values, say year or year and month. Anything processing the data can then deal with it however is appropriate for its context, say setting missing month and day values to 1, or mid range (month = June, day = 15) so the DOB can be represented as a Date object whether it's precise or not.

For data entry, let users select the type of date and enter values accordingly, e.g.

```js
function showDOBFields(evt) {
  // Get precision type
  let precision = document.querySelector('[name="datePrecision"]:checked').value;
  // Show controls based on checked radio button
  document.querySelectorAll('.dobSelect').forEach(
    el => el.style.display = el.id == precision? '' : 'none'
  );
}

// Add listeners to radio buttons
window.onload = function() {
  // Initialise display
  showDOBFields();
  // Add listeners
  document.querySelectorAll('[name="datePrecision"]').forEach(el =>
    el.addEventListener('click', showDOBFields)
  )
};
```

```css
.subHeading {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 110%;
}
.userInfo {
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<span class="subHeading">Date of birth</span>
<br>
Precise: <input type="radio" checked name="datePrecision" value="preciseDate"><span class="userInfo">Full date is known</span>
<br>
Approximate: <input type="radio" name="datePrecision" value="approximateDate"><span class="userInfo">Only an approximate date is known (year or year and month)</span>
<br>

<div id="preciseDate" class="dobSelect">
  <input type="date" id="dobPrecise">
</div>
<div id="approximateDate" class="dobSelect">
  <span class="userInfo">Input either year or year and month</span>
  <br>
  Year: <input type="number"><br>
  Month: <input type="number"><br>
</div>
```

When passing the data around, pass an object like:

```
{dateOfBirth: {
   precise: true,
   value: '1990-01-01'}
 }, 
{dateOfBirth: {
   precise: false,
   value: '1990'}
 },
```